# Any nonempty closed bounded set contains its LUB and GLB.

Tags: proof-writing

Although this seems intuitive, I don't quite see how to prove this.

A set $A$ is closed provided if $a_n \in A$ with $a_n \to p$, then $p \in A$. Since $A$ is bounded, then any nonempty $a_n \in A$ is also bounded so it has an LUB and GLB. But how do we know the LUB and GLB are within A?

<s>Also, the empty set is both closed and bounded, but how can it contain its LUB and GLB when it is inherently empty? Perhaps the empty set must be excluded?</s>

Edit: Title.

Comment: Check the definition of LUB and GLB again.  If I remember correctly, there is a nice sequence involved in their definitions.  Try using that along with what you noted about closed sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LUB and the GLB are only defined for non-empty sets, so you have to exculde the empty set.

Now, let $A$ be a non-empty closed and bounded set. Then $A$ has a LUB and a GLB. Put $l:=\sup A.$

Let's assume that $l\notin A.$

Now let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Since $l-\varepsilon<l$ and since $l$ is the least upper bound of $A$ then $l-\varepsilon<a$ for some $a\in A.$ Since $l\neq a$ (because $l\notin A$) and $a<l$ (because $l$ is an upper bound of $A$) then $0<|l-a|<\varepsilon$ and hence $l$ is a limit point of $A.$ Since $A$ is closed then $l\in A,$ which contradicts our original assumption that $l\notin A.$ Thus $l\in A.$ The same proof applies for $\inf A.$

Comment: I believe you mean $a < l$ rather than $a \leq l$ since $a \not = l$.

Comment: Yes, let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Proof without the method of contradiction.Let  $x=\text {lub } A$. Case 1: For some $y<x$, the open interval $(y,x)$ is disjoint from $A$. Then $x \in A$ otherwise $y$ is an upper bound for $A$ which is less than $\text {lub } A$, which is absurd.  Case 2 : For every $y<x$ we have $(y,x) \cap A \ne \phi$. Then for each $n \in N$ choose $z_n \in (x-2^{-n},x)\cap A$. Since $A$ is closed,and $\{z_n : n \in N\} \subset A $ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n =x$, we have $x \in A$.

Comment: Nice proof, but you are using the method of contradiction when you consider the first case (it is a small detail though and the whole proof "doesn't use contradiction").

Comment: It is almost impossible to write a proof of anything without that method somewhere in it.What I mean is that I did not aim to derive a contradiction from assuming  $x \not \in A$ at the outset.